# Could not find the correct Provider<Position> above this MapScreen Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Error:
Exception has occurred.
ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this MapScreen Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that MapScreen is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

I don't know how to fix this error.
Here my code :

```
class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MapScreen> createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

final locatorService = GeolocatorService();
final placesService = PlacesService();

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        FutureProvider(
          create: (context) => locatorService.getLocation(),
          initialData: locatorService.getLocation(),
        ),
        ProxyProvider<Position?, Future<List<Place>>>(
          update: (context, position, places) {
            return placesService.getPlaces(
                position!.latitude, position.longitude);
          },
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: getScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getScreen() {
    final currentPosition = Provider.of<Position>(context);
    final placesProvider = Provider.of<Future<List<Place>>?>(context);
    return FutureProvider(
      create: (context) => placesProvider,
      initialData: const [],
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded)),
            title: const Text('Tìm nhà hàng'),
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
          body: (currentPosition != null)
              ? Consumer<List<Place>>(
                  builder: (context, places, child) {
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          child: GoogleMap(
                            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                                target: LatLng(currentPosition.latitude,
                                    currentPosition.longitude),
                                zoom: 16.0),
                            zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: places.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Card(
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      title: Text(
                                        places[index].name,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }))
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                )
              : const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )),
    );
  }
}
```

I stuck with this error for 2 days. Please help me get out of this. Thank you everyone.

Comment: I think when you writing `Provider.of..` you are getting `context` above from multi-provider's build method so that's why it is throwing you this error

Comment: So I would suggest define multiprovider one more level above might be in your case in the `main` function or just create a stateless widget and add `getScreen` code in there. I think option 2 will be more clean and manageable for future.

Comment: I try to use your option 2 but it's still get error.